# how to cast an object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting

```js
import { Enseignant } from "./Enseignant";
import { AlreadyExistsError } from "./errors/AlreadyExistsError";
import { Etudiant } from "./Etudiant";

export class Utilisateur {
  private _id: string;
  private _first_name: string;
  private _last_name: string;
  private _email: string;
  private _token: string;

  private static user: Utilisateur;

  constructor(id: string, first_name: string, last_name: string, email: string, token: string) {
     this._id = id;
     this._first_name = first_name;
     this._last_name = last_name;
     this._email = email;
     this._token = token;
   }

  public static connectUser(id: string, first_name: string, last_name: string, email: string, token: string): Utilisateur {
    if (Utilisateur.user) {
      throw new AlreadyExistsError("Un utilisateur est deja connecte");
    } else {
      if(email.includes("teacher")) {
        Utilisateur.user  = new Enseignant(id, first_name, last_name, email, token);//TODO ajouter tout les params de Enseignant
      } else {
        // Utilisateur.user = new Etudiant(id, first_name, last_name, email, token, code_permanant );//TODO ajouter tout les params de Etudiant
      }
      // Utilisateur.user = new Utilisateur(id, first_name, last_name, email, token);
    }

    return Utilisateur.user;
  }

  public static getUtilisateurConnecte(): Utilisateur {
    return Utilisateur.user;
  }

  public getId() {
    return Utilisateur.user._id;
  }

  public getFirstName() {
    return Utilisateur.user._first_name;
  }

};
```

```js
import { Cours } from "./Cours";
import { NotFoundError } from "./errors/NotFoundError";
import { Utilisateur } from "./Utilisateur";

export class Enseignant extends Utilisateur {
    private _idEnseignant : string;
    private _mapCours : Map<string,Cours>;
    private _cours : Cours;

    

    constructor(idEnseignant:string, prenom:string, nom:string, email:string, token:string) {
        super(idEnseignant, prenom, nom, email, token);
        this._mapCours = new Map<string,Cours>();
        
    }

    public set setCours(cours: Cours){
        this._cours = cours;
    }
    public add(cours: Cours){
        this.mapCours.set(cours.sigle, cours)
    }

    public getCours(){
        return this._cours;
    }

   
    // moi
    public get Cours(){
        return this._cours;
    }

    public ajouterEtudiant(id:string, prenom:string, nom:string, email:string, codePermanent:string, sigle:string){
        let cours = this.getCoursSpecifique(sigle);
        cours.ajouterEtudiant(id,prenom,nom,email,codePermanent)
    }


    public get mapCours() {
        return this._mapCours;
    }

    public getCoursSpecifique(sigle:string){
        return this._mapCours.get(sigle);
    }

    

    /**
     * Utile pour : CU01b -demanderDetailsCours
     * Méthode permettant d'obtenir les informations du cours
     * Les informations sont le sigle, le titre, les détails 
     * du cours ainsi que la liste des codes permanents de tous 
     * les étudiants incrits dans un groupe cours associé à ce 
     * cours
     * @param sigle Le sigle du cours
     */
    public getInfosCours(sigle:string) {
        let cours = this._mapCours.get(sigle);

        if (cours === undefined) {
            // Le cours n'existe pas
            throw new NotFoundError("Cours '" + sigle + "'n'existe pas.");
        }

        let resultat = {
            messageSigle: "Sigle du cours : ",
            sigle: sigle,
            messageTitre: "Titre du cours : ",
            titre: cours.titre,
            messageDetails: "Détails du cours : ",
            detail: cours.detail
            //messageCP: "Code permenanents des étudiants inscrits : "
            //codePermanents: cours.getEtudiantsCours(),
        };
        
        return resultat; 
     
    }
   

    public toJSON() {
        return {
            "idEnseignant": this._idEnseignant,
        }
    }
}
```

in some method, im trying to do something like this

let teacher = Utilisateur.getUilisateurConnecter();

then I would like to call a function from Enseignant like this

teacher.add( new ... ) ;
But it says : property 'add' does not exist on type 'Utilisateur'
normally in java you can cast like : Animal n = new Dog()
I was thinking about doing something like this :
let teacher : Enseignant = Utilisateur.getUtilisateurConnecter()

Comment: Does `Utilisateur.getUilisateurConnecter` return a `Utilisateur` or a `Enseignant`. Not talking about the types here, what does it *actually* return?

Comment: Also please reduce your code samples. 90% is not needed, we don't need to see your actual code, just a minimal version that demonstrates the idea.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. If you know your `Utilisateur` is actually an `Enseignant`, you can use:

```
let enseignant = utilisateur as Enseignant;
```

However, it is worth noting that unlike Java, TypeScript will not verify at runtime that this cast is actually correct, so if your `utilisateur` happens to be an `Etudiant` instead, your code will proceed, and only fail much later when a property specific to `Enseignant` is required but not found.

If you don't know for sure what kind of `Utilisateur` it is, you can use `instanceof` to check since `Enseignant` is a class (if it were a mere interface you'd need to check the type differently):

```
if (utilisateur instanceof Enseignant) {
    let enseignant = utilisateur; // is known to be of type Enseignant
}
```